# Get value of a <td> onclick to an other <td> of the same row with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to get the value of a data cell `<td>` if I click to an other `<td>` of the same row.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
   <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
   <td>{{ x.Country | uppercase }}</td>
 </tr>
```

One way to solve it is for instance 
http://jsfiddle.net/L60L3gv9/

```
$scope.getValueOfTD = function(x){
    alert(x.Name);    
}
```

But in my case, there is no link between my data cells. Is there a way to get this value with a standard function like ?

```
$scope.getValueOfTD = function(){

}
```

Any solutions is okay

Comment: can you be a little more specific about your problem

Comment: can you put an ng-click on your <tr>?

Comment: Well, the point is to get the value of the other cell without using the properties of the list..

Comment: @Peege51 nope only on the td

Comment: What do you mean without using properties of the list?  That's what you're looping over.  You want the value of one of the properties...no?

Comment: Something like this actually : https://jsfiddle.net/syLuLob0/78/

Comment: Then yeah. ng-click on the tr... I just visited that jsfiddle. He's using properties of the list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-click` on the `tr`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z72tq5u3/)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <th>Column1</th>
  <th>Column2</th>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names" ng-click="getValueOfTD(x)">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country | uppercase }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getValueOfTD = function (user) {
    console.log(user.Name);
}
```

Comment: And what you would like to use?

Comment: I'd use ng-click on the <tr> :)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer the question. The Name and Country fields are just here to fill the table for example purpose. In my case I don't have any lists. Imagine my case like I fill the table myself giving a value for each cells. And I don't have any data coming from JSON/XML or any http requests. That say, I don't know if I'm clear yet